Swift concurrency warning. The compiler warns that my concurrent code will not compile in Swift 6 but all the variables are local
I want to try concurrent processing of an array for the first time.  The compiler gives this warning: "Mutation of captured var 'scaledImage' in concurrently-executing code; this is an error in Swift 6".
I then revised the code by copying the source array a local let variable; thus all the data are now local but the warning persisted.  Since all the data are now local and the array "scaledImage" is a 'sink' array I don't understand why the warning persists nor what to do about it.
    // Concurrent processing 1st attempt
    func processArrayConcurrently() async -> [UInt8] {
        var scaledImage = [UInt8]()
        scaledImage.reserveCapacity(self.backingImage!.count)
        // constants for the data
        let dMin = Double(self.backingMinMax[0])
        let dRange = Double(self.backingRange)
        let backingImage = self.backingImage!

        let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.concurrentQueue", attributes: .concurrent)

        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: backingImage.count) { index in
            let processedValue = UInt8(backingImage[index] * 2) // Example processing
            concurrentQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {  // WARNING next line
                scaledImage[index] = processedValue
            }
        }

        // Wait for all tasks to complete
        concurrentQueue.sync(flags: .barrier) {}

        return scaledImage
    }


Edit: Where image occurs in variable name, it refers to an array with data to be converted into an image.
My intended use is to allow the user to 'grab' a point on the image and 'mouse' it around to change the scaling and improve the image.  The images are all infrared views of wildfire consequently the range of values from unburned terrain to 'hot' pixels is much more that 255 counts so some processing is required.  This would let the user scale the lower pixel values differently from the higher values and see the results in real time.  I've done this in the remote past with C/C++.

You should not mix Swift's async with GCD. If you want to adopt Swift Concurrency, use a TaskGroup instead of concurrentPerform.

Actually, Apple explicitly advises that slow, synchronous work should not be done within Swift concurrency (as it violates the contract to never impede forward progress). They explicitly advise doing this work outside of Swift concurrency, i.e., they specifically suggest that this sort of work does belong in GCD and then bridge it back to Swift concurrency with a continuation. See Visualize and optimize Swift concurrency.

Wow.  I've edited my question.  This is CPU intensive. Later it will be really CPU intensive when I caluclate temperature from the camera's DN values. See my comment on Sweeper's answer.

The warning here is because Swift Concurrency doesn't understand all the semantics of GCD. In this case, it doesn't understand what .barrier means.
Even though scaledImage is local variable, it is captured in a @Sendable closure (the closure passed to concurrentQueue.async(flags: .barrier)), and at that point it becomes a shared state. The closure can be passed around across different threads and all sorts of things can happen as far as Swift Concurrency is concerned.
Bottom line is, you should not mix Swift Concurrency with GCD. If you want to use GCD, remove async and add a completion handler closure parameter. There are also some mistakes in your code to fix. reserveCapacity does not actually add anything to the array, so all the array accesses will be out-of-bounds. It seems like you want to do all the processing on concurrentQueue, but DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform runs on the current dispatch queue, which is definitely not concurrentQueue.
You can do something similar to Rob's answer here, where you write to a thread-safe array.
func processArrayConcurrently(completion: @escaping @Sendable ([UInt8]) -> Void) {
    let backingImage = self.backingImage

    let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.concurrentQueue", attributes: .concurrent)

    concurrentQueue.async {
        let scaledImage = SynchronizedArray<UInt8>(count: backingImage.count, defaultValue: 0)
        // concurrentPerform should be called in concurrentQueue.async!
        // otherwise this won't be run on concurrentQueue
        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: backingImage.count) { index in
            // you might want to check Task.isCancelled here if you plan on using this from Swift Concurrency
            // if Task.isCancelled { return }
            let processedValue = UInt8(backingImage[index] * 2) // Example processing
            scaledImage[index] = processedValue
        }
        completion(scaledImage.wrappedValue)
    }
}

final class SynchronizedArray<Value>: @unchecked Sendable {
    private var values: [Value]
    private let lock = NSLock()
    
    init(count: Int, defaultValue: Value) {
        values = .init(repeating: defaultValue, count: count)
    }

    subscript(index: Int) -> Value {
        get { lock.withLock { values[index] } }
        set { lock.withLock { values[index] = newValue } }
    }

    var wrappedValue: [Value] {
        get { lock.withLock { values } }
        set { lock.withLock { values = newValue } }
    }
}

You can then write an async wrapper of this like so
func processArrayConcurrently() async -> [UInt8] {
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        processArrayConcurrently {
            continuation.resume(returning: $0)
        }
    }
}


If the task you are doing is not CPU-intensive, you can also do this purely with Swift Concurrency using a TaskGroup.
func processArrayConcurrently() async -> [UInt8] {
    let dMin = Double(self.backingMinMax[0])
    let dRange = Double(self.backingRange)
    let backingImage = self.backingImage

    return await withTaskGroup(of: (index: Int, image: UInt8).self) { group in
        var scaledImage = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: backingImage.count)
        for (i, image) in backingImage.enumerated() {
            group.addTask {
                (i, UInt8(image * 2)) // do some processing
            }
        }
        for await (i, image) in group {
            scaledImage[i] = image
        }
        return scaledImage
    }
}

This creates a task group with subtask results of type (Int, UInt8). The Int is for recording the index of the scaledImage that the UInt8 (the actual result) should be inserted to.
As long as processArrayConcurrently is not isolated to any actor, the processing will run in a background thread.

Yeah, @unchecked Sendable type resolves the compiler warning. I wish there was a way to apply that to a single function (with local buffers) rather than a type, to tell the compiler “hey, I’ve got it from here”. I understand their reluctance to do that, but having done a lot of pixel buffer parallel routines with Unsafe[Mutable][Raw][Buffer]Pointer (which can eliminate the synchronization overhead when done right) it is a bit awkward to have create types to wrap these legacy buffers. Swift has swung from “not enough thread-safety features” to “too many”, IMHO. But good answer (+1).

This is really a lot for one who is just learning Swift/SwiftUI.  I think I will accept Sweeper's answer but learn more about all this and come back to it after other aspects of my App work.  Unless someone objects to the acceptance.  I've edited my question.

No objections here!

@Rob It is possible to do nonisolated(unsafe) var scaledImage = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: backingImage.count). Is that similar to what you were looking for? I don't know how to synchronise it though (or is it already safe because we are never accessing the same indices of the array more than once?).

Yes, a nonisolated(unsafe) var was precisely what I was looking for. And, in answer to your question, if we use [UInt8] (or Data), then we have to manually synchronize it (probably with a lock, but we can use any traditional synchronization mechanism). If you use UnsafeMutableBufferPointer, though, no synchronization is needed as there is no overlapping accesses to individual bytes.

Wow!  One thing I forgot to mention is the usage, the code is only executed when the cursor is hovering over the image and the app doesn't accept any keyboard input.  The user can't change anything until the mouse is not hovering.

@NateLockwood that sounds like a problem on the call site. Make sure this is not isolated to the main actor. Mark it as nonisolated. If you still have problems, I suggest making a [mre] and posting a new question.

I believe that Sweeper answered your question: To let the compiler know that you have manually synchronized your access to your buffer, you would either use nonisolated(unsafe) var, or wrap it in a type that is designated as @unchecked Sendable.
A few observations, each subsequent alternative offering a further performance benefit:

There is no point in using a concurrent queue for synchronization if all of your calls are going to use barriers. If you wanted to use GCD for synchronization, what you’ve got here is equivalent to a serial queue (and no barrier would be needed).
The only time we would use a concurrent queue is when implementing the “reader-writer” pattern (where writes, frequently asynchronously dispatched, are done with a barrier and reads are done synchronously, but without any barrier). In some cases, this “reader-writer” approach offers a modest performance improvement over the serial queue, notably when you want to enjoy parallel reads, but want the writes synchronized.
But the reader-writer only offers benefits when you are doing a lot of reads while the buffer is being intermittently mutated, which is not applicable in your example. And, besides, the reader-writer pattern only offers a very modest improvement over a serial queue, but does introduce lots of additional complexities (e.g., you can suffer from thread-explosions). Besides, locks (discussed below) are almost always far more performant than either of these GCD synchronization techniques.

Personally, I would use a lock: NSLock is simple and faster than GCD queues, OSAllocatedUnfairLock is even faster and eliminates the nonisolated(unsafe) var and/or @unchecked Sendable workarounds:
import os.lock

nonisolated func processParallel(backingImage: [UInt8]) async -> [UInt8] {
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        let count = backingImage.count
        let lock = OSAllocatedUnfairLock(initialState: [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: count))

        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: count) { index in
            let processedValue = UInt8(UInt16(backingImage[index]) * 2 % 256) // Example processing
            lock.withLock { buffer in
                buffer[index] = processedValue
            }
        }
        lock.withLock { buffer in
            continuation.resume(returning: buffer)
        }
    }
}


Alternatively, you can use a UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8>, and because your algorithm guarantees that no individual byte in that buffer is mutated in parallel, no synchronization is needed at all:
nonisolated func processParallel(backingImage: [UInt8]) async -> [UInt8] {
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        let count = backingImage.count
        nonisolated(unsafe) let buffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: count)
        defer { buffer.deallocate() }

        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: count) { index in
            let processedValue = UInt8(UInt16(backingImage[index]) * 2 % 256) // Example processing
            buffer[index] = processedValue
        }
        continuation.resume(returning: [UInt8](buffer))
    }
}

Note, this technique of dropping the synchronization cannot be done with Array<UInt8> (aka, [UInt8]) or Data types, but you can get away with it when using Unsafe[Mutable][Raw][Buffer]Pointer types.

You should “stride” to reduce the number of context switches. E.g., let us image that your buffer has 10m bytes, you really do not want to do 10m context switches. Instead, have each iteration process 100k or 1m points:
nonisolated func processStriding(backingImage: [UInt8]) async -> [UInt8] {
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        let count = backingImage.count
        nonisolated(unsafe) let buffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: count)
        defer { buffer.deallocate() }

        let stride = 1_000_000
        var (iterations, remainder) = count.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: stride)
        if remainder != 0 {
            iterations += 1
        }

        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: iterations) { i in
            let start = i * stride
            let end = min(start + stride, count)
            for index in start ..< end {
                let processedValue = UInt8(UInt16(backingImage[index]) * 2 % 256) // Example processing
                buffer[index] = processedValue
            }
        }
        continuation.resume(returning: [UInt8](buffer))
    }
}

This will confer a significant performance benefit. But you will want to play around with different striding factors and experimentally verify which striding factor offers the best performance. For me, using a buffer with 10m items, serial algorithm took 64.1 msec, while the parallel algorithm striding every 100,000 items took 3.2 msec, and a parallel algorithm with no striding took 1060 msec. That non-striding parallel approach is 16× slower the simple serial algorithm. Now part of this is exaggerated because the demo calculation is so trivial (so the modest parallelism overhead will appear disproportionately large), but it illustrates the point: If you’re going for parallelism, striding can yield significant performance benefits.

A minor point, but your question does not share where you got this [UInt8] “image” to start with, but if you, for example, extracted it from a CGImage data provider, you might not want to use [UInt8] at all, but just access the CGBitmapContextGetData data directly (or whatever) and avoid these high-level data types altogether. Manipulating native image buffers results in more complex code, but it frequently will be far more performant than round-tripping through [UInt8].

As a final observation, before you lose too much sleep optimizing parallel calculations on the CPU, there are many custom frameworks for image processing (e.g., the Accelerate, CoreImage, Vision, etc.). These offer a dizzying array of specialized, highly-optimized algorithms, and many are GPU-based.
So, before you go too far in writing your own parallelized CPU-based algorithms, I would suggest seeing if there is an existing framework that can be leveraged to better solve your specific business problem. And I would not dwell on the simplified “multiply by 2” sort of problem, but focus on the actual business problem you are trying to solve, as the implementations might be radically different from each other. E.g., one sort of approach might be relevant if you really want to multiply every byte by some scalar, but if you are planning on something more substantive, all the work in the “vector/matrix times scalar” details becomes irrelevant.
This obviously is far beyond the scope of this question, but just a word of advice.


